# Simple PHP Class Question regarding methods

Tags: php, class, object, methods

I have a simple question regarding PHP Classes.

Multiple times I have seen other class-frameworks etc use method calls like.

```
$post->data->text();
```

I like this functionality, rather than just doing something like this.

```
$post->dataReturnAsText();
```

But i'm not quite sure how they created this functionality to have perhaps a 'sub-method'? Hope someone can point me in the right direction....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you provide has nothing special:

```
<?php

class Post{
    public $data;
}

class Data{
    public function text(){
    }
}

$post = new Post;
$post->data = new Data;
$post->data->text();
```

However, you've probably found it in the context of method chaining (very popular in JavaScript libraries):

```
<?php

class Foo{
    public function doThis(){
        return $this;
    }

    public function doThat(){
        return $this;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->doThis()->doThat()->doThis();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, data is simply a attribute of the class, and it contains another object:

```
class data
{
    public function text()
    {
    }
}

class thing
{
    public $data;
}

$thing = new thing();
$thing->data = new data();
$thing->data->text();
```

Answer (score 0):

its probably a just that the "data" is a a public property of $post  containing an object wth a text property for example :

```
class Textable {
    public $text;

    function __construct($intext) {
      $this->text = $intext;
    } 
}

class Post {

  public $data;

  function __construct() {
      $data = new Textable("jabberwocky");
  } 

}
```

this will allow you to do :

```
$post = new Post();
echo( $post->data->text ); // print out "jabberwocky"
```

of course the right OOP way is to make the property *private* and allow access useing a getter function but that besides the point...